# operate on different sections of stdin without intermediate file

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

Is there a simple way to do this with redirection or pipes without creating FILE1?  I want to apply process2 to the body of the output of process1, without touching the first and last few lines.

```
process1 >FILE1
head -n 3 FILE1
tail -n +4 FILE1|head -n -4|process2 # producing output
tail -n 4 FILE1
rm -f FILE1
```

Comment: apparently my <CR> dont show

Comment: process1 >FILE1
head -n 3 FILE1
tail -n +4 FILE1|head -n -4|process2 # producing output
tail -n 4 FILE1
rm -f FILE1

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do ? which commands ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just pipe them : to process every line from process1 except
the first and last, say, 3 lines:

```
process1 | tail -n +4 | head -n -3 | process2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this is supposed to achieve but here is a solution that does exactly what you're doing without using an intermediate file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# prevent LF from being removed
export IFS=' '

output=`process1`
echo $output | head -n 3

echo $output | tail -n +4 | head -n -4 | process2 # producing output
echo $output | tail -n 4
```